# telepresence: error: connector service did not start: timeout while waiting for connector to start

Tags: kubernetes, telepresence

when I tried to connect the telepresence in macOS with M1 chip using `telepresence connect` command, shows error like this:

```
W0830 19:51:29.367038   94595 native_arm64.go:52] Could not read /proc/cpuinfo: open /proc/cpuinfo: no such file or directory
W0830 19:51:29.367073   94595 native_arm64.go:177] Could not read /proc/self/auxv: open /proc/self/auxv: no such file or directory
Launching Telepresence User Daemon
telepresence: error: connector service did not start: timeout while waiting for connector to start
If you think you have encountered a bug, please run `telepresence gather-logs` and attach the telepresence_logs.zip to your github issue or create a new one: https://github.com/telepresenceio/telepresence/issues/new?template=Bug_report.md .
```

this is the telepresence version info:

```
➜  reddwarf-admin git:(main) telepresence version
W0830 19:54:30.187911   94876 native_arm64.go:52] Could not read /proc/cpuinfo: open /proc/cpuinfo: no such file or directory
W0830 19:54:30.187944   94876 native_arm64.go:177] Could not read /proc/self/auxv: open /proc/self/auxv: no such file or directory
Client: v2.7.2 (api v3)
Root Daemon: v2.7.2 (api v3)
User Daemon: not running
```

does anyone facing the same issue? why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this problem? I have tried this command:

```
telepresence quit -ur
sudo pkill -SIGTERM -f daemon-foreground
pkill -SIGTERM -f connector-foreground
telepresence connect
```

I also have tried to upgrade the telepresence version to 2.8.2. The problem still remain.

```
➜  cruise-open git:(main) telepresence version
Client: v2.8.2 (api v3)
Root Daemon: v2.8.2 (api v3)
User Daemon: not running
➜  cruise-open git:(main) telepresence connect
Launching Telepresence User Daemon
telepresence: error: connector service did not start: timeout while waiting for connector to start
If you think you have encountered a bug, please run `telepresence gather-logs` and attach the telepresence_logs.zip to your github issue or create a new one: https://github.com/telepresenceio/telepresence/issues/new?template=Bug_report.md .
```

does anyone facing the same problem? I also tried command like this:

```
mkdir -p /Users/$USER/Library/Caches/telepresence
```

still could not fixed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am tried to using this command and fixed this error:

```
brew upgrade datawire/blackbird/telepresence
telepresence quit -s
sudo telepresence connect
```